# Is there any way that I conditionally skip a scenario in Cucumber java?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

Is there any way that I conditionally skip a scenario in Cucumber java?

In below images, I want to skip the scenarios written for data check when no data is available in press release section.

I am planning to first check for no data available scenario, if it is executed successfully then skip the rest of the scenarios.

[image: When No Data is Available]

[image: When Data is Available]

Adding feature file for more understainding :

Background: 
    Given Home page is displayed
    When I navigates to "XYZ" menu
    Then "Press release" section should be displayed

```
@News    
And "Press release" section should I check for No data present

@News 
And "Press release" section should feature "latest News" portion 
And "Press release" section having "abc" link for pagination

@News
And in "Press release" section click on news link 
Then news details should be displayed
```

In Above file, 
    if  @News
    And "Press release" section should I check for No data present

returns positive result, then my rest of the scenarios falling under tag @News should be spiked, instead of checking the same condition in each and every scenario.

Comment: Are you talking off steps in a scenario or skipping whole scenarios? Can you add your feature file in the question?

Comment: You can have a step that checks for data and adds data if none found. Use steps as precondition. Given ... And i have some data Then ..., or i don't have any data.

Comment: added sample feature file

Comment: can it be achieved using cucumber harness(I don't have much idea about it, if anyone knows can help) as explain in below link?
http://search.cpan.org/~bdr/Test-BDD-Cucumber-0.17/lib/Test/BDD/Cucumber/Harness.pm

By calling .
scenario_done

Called at the start and end of scenario execution respectively. Both methods accept a Test::BDD::Cucmber::Model::Scenario module and a dataset hash.

Comment: Dose any one have any kind of solution to this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [QAF-Gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) you can do it by using [step listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#teststep-listener). For example on step failure warp original exception to AutomationError and your scenario will get skipped instead of failure. You also can set step-meta-data and use it in listener. Here is code sample:

```
    //This will called on step failure
    @Override
    public void onFailure(StepExecutionTracker stepExecutionTracker) {
        TestStep step = stepExecutionTracker.getStep();
        String myCustomMetaDataVal = (String) step.getMetaData().get("my-custom-meta-data");
        if ("somevlaue".equalsIgnoreCase(myCustomMetaDataVal)) {
            Throwable originalThrowable = stepExecutionTracker.getException();
            stepExecutionTracker.setException(new AutomationError("meaningful message", originalThrowable));
        }
    }
```